# ClassNotFoundException, heroku postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, heroku

The issue is at

`class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")`

pom.xml has this dependency:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1203-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
```

The error is

`java: unreported exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`

That should be all the important stuff. If more stuff is needed for figuring stuff out, heres all of it. (dont really care if i release the database it'll be deleted since its just a test)

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Database-Test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1203-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

**Main Class**

```java
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBTEST{
    public static void main (String[]args) throws SQLException, URISyntaxException{
        System.out.println(getConnection());
    }
    private static Connection getConnection() throws URISyntaxException, SQLException{
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        //String dbUrl = System.getenv("DATABASE_URL");
        String dbUrl = "postgres://fxeymwfokhsimv:bd5c9975533c20ed3ab4df7c0ea263911207854c2cac46983fafce18689a1161@ec2-184-72-162-198.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dlfvrduvj5qcr";
        return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
    }
}
```

**FILE PATH**

[image: File Path]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the version of driver you have specified in your maven and the aws instance is same.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1203-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I probably sound big dumb but... what is an aws instance?

Comment: Looking at your exception stack: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for postgres://fxeymwfokhsimv:bd5c9975533c20ed3ab4df7c0ea263911207854c2cac46983fafce18689a1161@ec2-184-72-162-198.compute-1.amazonaws.com you are trying to use amazon Elastic compute. you have put scope as provided, which mean that it should be available. If its not already, remove provided scope.

Comment: How do I check? It was generated as the URL when I provisioned the Heroku PostgreSQL database. Sorry that I forgot to say that it was done for Heroku.

Comment: Remove provided scope for the dependency and then run.

Comment: It changed the error message, but now a new one popped up (or maybe it was there before and I just now noticed it).
java: unreported exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown. The error also seems to occur at the same line.

Comment: try using the dependency I added. Looks like your current version is not having the class mentioned and hence CNF exception

Comment: Doesn't seem to have changed anything - is there an extra step or something for IntelliJ Idea?

Comment: yep: the driver url should have this form: jdbc:postgresql://fxeymwfokhsimv:bd5c9975533c20ed3ab4df7c0ea263911207854c2cac46983fafce18689a1161@ec2-184-72-162-198.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dlfvrduvj5qcr

Comment: I changed the URL, but the error is still `java: unreported exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`. I checked my libraries, and I wonder if it might have something to do with it - the files under sources and javadocs is red, but the classes is white. Not sure if that has anything to do with anything, but I thought i should mention it.

Comment: Search if Driver class is there in the package where you are doing Class.forName()

Comment: It's in the external libraries portion. Tried dragging it up to the java folder (no package) but it wouldn't do anything. How do I add it?